# Error in output in Bestsum Memoization problem

Tags: python, memoization

So I was doing this sum, and could not get the correct output for particular cases.

```
def bestsum(targetsum,numbers,memo={}):
    if targetsum in memo: 
        return memo[targetsum]
    if targetsum==0:
        return []
    elif targetsum<0:
        return None
    shortest=None

    for i in numbers:
        '''print (targetsum)
        print (i)'''
        const=targetsum-i
        result=bestsum(const,numbers,memo)
        if result !=None:
            result.append(i)
            if shortest==None or len(result)<len(shortest):
                shortest=result.copy()
    
    memo[targetsum]=shortest       
    return shortest`
```

Input was
**print(bestsum(15,[3,2,5]))**
Output was
**[3,3,3,3,3]**

But if input list changed to `[5,2,3]`, I get Output as `[5,5,5]`

**Input :`100,[5,3,2,25]`**

**Output: `[25,5,3,2,25,5,3,2,25,5,3,2,25,5,3,2]`**

Pls help and explain the scenario

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Q1: what does the `copy` do?
In Python, the `=` actually does not create new memories to save the real value, instead, it creates a `pointer` that saves the address to the original memories. For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
c = a.copy()
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
```

will print the same address for `a` and `b`, but not for `c`, as

```
140357251344512
140357251344512
140357251348544
```

(These values may vary for different runs, which is normal.)
So for those mutable types, such as lists, dictionaries, and sets, once we modify the value of `b`, actually we modify the value saved on the address, unfortunately, `a` that ref to this address will be changed at the same time.
But with `copy`, we will force Python to create a new memory for `c`, so that anything that happens on the new memory will not affect the original one.

Q2: Optimize the code.
See below:

```
def bestsum_opt(targetsum,numbers,memo={}):
    # print("Call for ", targetsum)
    global call_counter
    call_counter += 1
    if targetsum in memo: 
        return memo[targetsum].copy() if memo[targetsum] else None
    shortest=None

    for i in numbers:
        const=targetsum-i
        if const < 0:
            # judge here instead in another function call
            continue
        if const == 0:
            # if const is 0, of cause no other shorter path
            memo[targetsum] = [i]
            return [i]
        
        result = bestsum_opt(const,numbers,memo)
        
        if result !=None:
            result.append(i)
            if shortest==None or len(result)<len(shortest):
                shortest=result
        else:
            print(const,numbers,memo)
    
    memo[targetsum]=shortest
    return memo[targetsum].copy() if memo[targetsum] else None
```

and add the same `call_counter` things to the original code.
Running the following code,

```
call_counter = 0
bestsum(15, [3,2,5], memo={})
print(call_counter)
call_counter = 0
bestsum_opt(15, [3,2,5], memo={})
print(call_counter)
```

you will find the number of function calls reduced from 43 to 32, and with `bestsum_opt(15, sorted(a, reverse=True), memo={})`, it will further reduce to 30.
Maybe there are many other works to further optimize the code, hope you good luck.

---

A fatal Bug in code:
The value of the `memo` dict is `shortest`, a `list` that can be modified. It was returned to the `result`, but then appended a new num. So the `memo` will contain wrong memories.
Add `print` before and after the `result.append(i)` line, and you will see the following output:

```
before append  {1: None, 3: [3]}
after  append  {1: None, 3: [3, 3]}
```

To fix this, add `copy()` to the return lines, as

```
def bestsum(targetsum,numbers,memo={}):
    if targetsum in memo: 
        return memo[targetsum].copy() if memo[targetsum] else None
    if targetsum==0:
        return []
    elif targetsum<0:
        return None
    shortest=None

    for i in numbers:
        '''print (targetsum)
        print (i)'''
        const=targetsum-i
        result = bestsum(const,numbers,memo)
        
        if result !=None:
            print('before append ', memo)
            result.append(i)
            print('after  append ', memo)
            if shortest==None or len(result)<len(shortest):
                shortest=result.copy()
    
    memo[targetsum]=shortest
    return shortest.copy() if shortest else None
```

This will give the correct answer for `bestsum(15, [3,2,5], memo={})` => `[5,5,5]`, and also for `bestsum(100, [5,3,2,25], memo={})` => `[25,25,25,25]`.

By the way, the `memo` remains among different calls, this may be related to the heap or stack things, but I'm not very sure. Actually, it's not a bug, but it is annoying for debugging.

And as you can see in the print logs, this code does a lot of meanless work, maybe you should optimize this before any further work.

Comment: Thanks so much. But, I am unable to understand what exactly the copy() at the end does.
Pls, explain :)
And also pls tell me where to optimize. I can't figure out where to do it.

Comment: TL;DR: As for Python, the `=` does not create a real memory for the value, instead,  it creates a `pointer` that saves the address to the value's original memory.  More details will be updated in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got my mistake and understood what to do.